# What are open source ffmpeg players for iOS/Android?

Tags: android, ios, ffmpeg

I have been searching for open source ffmpeg player, and I found somes. But I think there is a lot more out there. If you know one, please drop a line in the comment or answer. I'm working on iOS but really want to look further to see what has been made for Android

Here are what i found:

1. Mooncatventures group
   https://github.com/mooncatventures-group
2. KxMoviePlayer (use OpenGLES, Core Audio)
   https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmovie
3. FFmpeg for ios (with OpenGLES, AudioQueue)
   https://github.com/flyhawk007/FFmpeg-for-iOS.git
4. iFrameExtractor
   https://github.com/lajos/iFrameExtractor.git

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming-related Q&A not for general discussions, list or polls. If you have a specific programming problem then feel free to post it.

Comment: I think this  is sort of programming related QA. Asking for sample codes, like a tutorial list. I'm not sure that these kind of questions are prohibited on SO. Anyway looks need to be converted into community wiki.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/

Answer (score 4):

[ServeStream](http://sourceforge.net/projects/servestream/) - Streaming Media Player for Android.

Answer (score 2):

Debatable wether this is a proper question for stack overflow  For IOS you seem to have a pretty good list, there are a couple others , personally I can address our mooncatventures offering which most likely would be rtspplay, I'm not really all that familiar with kxmovie, it looks promising but requires the files on the device. Iframeextractor, extracts raw frames nothing more , nothing less.

As for Android I can definitely offer advice because we just finished building a player for a client.

We started with dolphin-player which is an open source player for android. 
Use the native rather than the custom player, what you mainly want is the sdl and JNI wrappers , which are the biggest pain with android.

The native player is just ffplay, the sdl linux player included with the ffmpeg distribution. SDL can be troublesome on Iphone but is still doable as we show with rtspplay, on Android there are no issues with using SDL, there are parts of Android OS that depend on it.

You need to modify ffplay, this can be difficult but fortunately we were able to reuse a lot of the ios coding, again the nasty part is the JNI wrapper and opengl  and using the dolphin player as the base made that a bit easier.

This is how we did it, If you need help please feel free to contact us.

Comment: Remark about kxmovie. Since kxmovie is based on ffmpeg, it supports remote streams like rtsp and rtmp.

Comment: Hi Michelle, I need to rotate video captured in landscape mode to portrait and also I need to show Frame By Frame Video in VideoView when video is in pause mode. How can I achieve this things using FFMPEG in android. If you have any sample code related to this, please share the code.

Comment: Michelle, regarding the player you set up, is it able to play 1080p movies? Dolphin player itself does not - neither JJ Player, a result from JJMpeg efforts.

Comment: dolphin was just the starting point we made a lot of mods, I don't know if it can play 1080p we don't get a lot of requests for that

Comment: @MichelleCannon - Hi,Actually we are implementing video player using FFMPEG for supporting all video formats with the reference of dolphin player. But, some videos are strucking and Audio, video not synchronizing. Will you give some information about this or any useful links ?

Answer (score 1):

For Java/Android, the following is one of them:

[JJMPEG](http://code.google.com/p/jjmpeg/)